# The use of prototype in javascript (comparsion with constructor and how to use it)

Tags: javascript

why should i use prototypes is js?

for example if i want to create a constructor like:

```
var Person = function(name, yearOfBirth){
    this.name = name;
    this.yearOfBirth = yearOfBirth;
    this.calculateAge = function(){
        console.log(2018-this.yearOfBirth);
    }
}
```

is better to use prototype for functions like:

```
var Person = function(name, yearOfBirth){
    this.name = name;
    this.yearOfBirth = yearOfBirth;
}


Person.prototype.calculateAge  = function(){
    console.log(2018-this.yearOfBirth);
}
```

should i use prototype also for props like name etc?

Can someone tell me the differences between using or not prototypes and what's the best use of it?

Thanks

EDIT: **this is the best answer that i've found**: https://hackernoon.com/prototypes-in-javascript-5bba2990e04b

Comment: `age` should actually be a getter.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**`Prototype` properties are shared across all instances of the constructor function.**

In your case the `calculateAge` function need not be required as a separate instance for all objects that you create out of Person and hence can be moved to `Prototype`, whereas properties like `name` and `yearOfBirth` need a separate instance for each object that you create from `Person`

You can define Prototypes properties on constructor functions when you wish to create a common property shared across all instances of the function.

Comment: so, in general, i should use prototypes for stuff that doesn't need to be instanced every time to improve the performance?

Comment: @ClaudioBiselli  yes, and for non-static properties